# no logro enlace con bd remota

Tags: phpmyadmin

Tengo montada una bd MySQL en mi hosting, requiero consultar los datos de la misma desde un formulario en mi website,localmente no existe problema pero,no logro el enlace con con la bd remota, se que es un problema de URL mio.

```
http://www.miwebpage.com
```

acceso a mi webpage sin problema pero, como ubico o complemento el URL para enlazar con la bd remota.
Espero el haber sido claro...

Comment: Hola. Muestra cómo haces el enlace en tu servidor local. Para poder indicarte los cambios a realizar en tu sitio web. Lo típico en los servidores compartidos es crear un usuario para la bd (en la página de administración del sitio) y asignarle privilegios y luego registrar sus credenciales en el código que la accesa.

Comment: <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1',root','pass');
mysqli_select_db($conn,"tabla");
?>

Comment: No entiendo el problema planteado. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Has depurado algo? ¿Con qué resultados? ¿Tienes errores? ¿Qué errores?

Comment: Hace falta información. 1. ¿Como administras tu hosting? quizás cPanel. 2. ¿Cómo creaste la BD remota? 2.1. Usaste una opción administrativa en hosting o phpMyAdmin? 3. ¿Has agregado un usuario con privilegios a dicha BD? (para usarlo en el comando de conexión). Agrega esa información a tu pregunta y el código para crear la conexión sin revelar claves pero evidenciando el uso de credenciales

Comment: Gracias tema resuelto